# How to get the most duplicates in 2d list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2d list with more than more than 20 rows. I would like to sorted and return the most duplicates in each sublist.For example, here is my list below

```
 list1 = [[a,a,b, b, b, v,v,v,v,x,x,p], [b, c, d, c], [a, j,j,j,c,c,f,f,h,h,h,h]]
```

I would like my result to be like this.

```
 List2 = [[b,v,a,x],[c],[h,j,c,f]]
```

Comment: There are more v's than b's in the first list, so shouldn't the result be `[[v,b,a,x],[c],[h,j,c,f]]`?

Comment: Based on your result, I'm guessing the question you WANTED to ask was "how can I get only the items that were duplicated?"  Is that correct?  That's easy with `collections.Counter`.

Comment: When you say "duplicated" I assume you mean "repeated". For example, in your first sub-list the value *v* is **not** duplicated - it's quadruplicated or, arguably, duplicated twice. Also, can you explain the rationale behind the required output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution using a Counter:

```
import collections

list1 = [["a","a","b","b","b","v","v","v","v","x","x","p"],["b","c","d","c"],["a","j","j","j","c","c","f","f","h","h","h","h"]]
list2 = []
for l in list1:
    c = collections.Counter(l)
    list2.append( [k for k,v in c.items() if v > 1] )
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'v', 'x'], ['c'], ['j', 'c', 'f', 'h']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Counter.most_common` to get the items in the sublist in order of frequency. `v` is more common than `b` here:

```py
from collections import Counter

a="a"; b="b"; c="c"; d="d"; f="f"; h="h"; j="j"; p="p"; v="v"; x="x"
ll = [[a,a,b, b, b, v,v,v,v,x,x,p], [b, c, d, c], [a, j,j,j,c,c,f,f,h,h,h,h]]

ls = [[e for e, n in Counter(items).most_common() if n >= 2] for items in ll]
print(ls)  # [['v', 'b', 'a', 'x'], ['c'], ['h', 'j', 'c', 'f']]
```